# Cursor hover the header on IOS Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When input is on focus on input and I scroll the screen the cursor stay hover the header on IOS.

ionic info

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.13

[image]

Comment: anyone have this ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I know of is to make the form multi step so there is no scroll. From what I've read it's a bug with no solution confirmed by the ionic team.